# Can't ssh to my server if ufw is disabled

Tags: server, ssh, firewall, ufw

Yesterday I changed the default ssh port in my server to 6000. Now here is my problem: When the server boots up, *ufw* is inactive. This results to not being able to `ssh` to my machine. However, when I do `ufw enable` on my server, `ssh` works fine. I am using Ubuntu server 16.04. Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: This seems strange, since when *ufw* is disabled, all ports must be accessible.

Comment: after you boot your server, with ufw disabled, what do you get for `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L`?

Comment: Here is the output : https://pastebin.com/Y2KkMLTU